# How to find the best exploration parameter in a Monte Carlo tree search?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, monte-carlo

I've developed a [Monte Carlo tree search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search) in checkers.

Here is my question. What should be the value of $C$, the exploration parameter in the following formula described in [*Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS)*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-monte-carlo-tree-search-mcts/)?

$$ S_i=x_i+C\sqrt{\frac{\ln (t)}{n_i}}$$

General consensus is that a value of $\sqrt 2$ should be used, but when I use a value of 10 it works, which save me a lot of time.

So, how can I find the best value for $C$, that best suits my problem?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. People shouldn't have to follow a link to find out what you're even asking, and if that link dies (and it will, eventually), your question will make no sense at all.

Comment: Try several different values, and see which one works best.

Answer (score 3):

The  value  of $C = \sqrt 2$  was  shown to ensure the asymptotic optimality when rewards are in the $[0,1]$ range ([Kocsis, Szepesvári, 2006](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~afern/classes/cs533/notes/uct.pdf)).

In many games, that reward range is straightforward: maximum and minimum possible scores can be *translated* to `0` and `1` (`0` could mean a loss and `1` a win).

The accuracy of this *squashing* seems to have a minimal impact (e.g. [Using Domain Knowledge to Improve Monte-Carlo Tree Search Performance in Parameterized Poker Squares](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj4q8mItqrkAhUWwAIHHSyeB-cQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aaai.org%2Focs%2Findex.php%2FAAAI%2FAAAI16%2Fpaper%2Fdownload%2F11809%2F12186&usg=AOvVaw3dKXKgvhbnBmo3bxYJ_Ciy) - Robert Arrington, Clay Langley, and Steven Bogaerts - 2016).

Unfortunately squashing isn't always possible.

With rewards outside the $[0, 1]$ range and/or for fine-tuning the [Cross Entropy Method](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/96b0/ef6ea3ddc24a9ee0bba23f8bb49db9243510.pdf) works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with whatever the literature recommends is a reasonable value without knowing any specifics of your problem. Otherwise, it is perfectly possible (and even to be expected) that a good value of $C$ will depend not only on your problem, but on the details of your instances.

In general with all (meta)heuristics, a good choice of parameters comes down to experimentation.